# Why doesn't undercurl use underline in my terminal?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, terminal, highlight

[`:help undercurl`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#undercurl) states:

> "undercurl" is a curly underline. ***When "undercurl" is not possible then "underline" is used.*** In general "undercurl" and "strikethrough" is only available in the GUI.

But if I run Vim with `vim --clean` and then issue the following commands, then the text `curl` is not highlighted in any way:

```
:hi Curl cterm=undercurl
:match Curl /curl/
```

However, if I change `undercurl` to `underline`, then `curl` is now underlined:

```
:hi Curl cterm=underline
```

Is the documentation wrong? Or am I just misinterpreting it?*

Or is the problem that Vim thinks that undercurl *is* possible and is therefore (unsuccessfully) attempting to use it? If this is the case, then what causes this? `:set t_Cs?` and `:set t_Ce?` both report that the settings are not set:

```
t_Cs=
t_Ce=
```

I'm running Vim 8.0.1420 inside iTerm2 v3.2.6 on macOS.

<sub>* It *could* be read to mean that there are some circumstances when undercurl is *available* but isn't *possible* and only in those cases will it be replaced with an underline.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is [just a bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2424), which was fixed just after the version I'm using, in [patch 8.0.1422](https://github.com/adizero/vim/commit/2fe5a21852705932719e6b7acd80c1b275103797).

Comment: here I am, in the distant future, still having this same problem with vim 9.1.80. Under both konsole and xterm.